# Stop sticky bootstrap column once it reaches div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have simple bootstrap row with two columns:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <p>All the way with you</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-5" id="stay">
    <p>So happy to go</p>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="stop">
  <p>DON'T GO HERE.</p>
</div>
```

Thanks to this script, the column with id #stay will follow the first column all the way down:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function($) {
      var element = $('#stay'),
          originalY = element.offset().top;

      // Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
      var topMargin = 10;

      // Should probably be set in CSS; but here just for emphasis
      element.css('position', 'relative');

      $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
          var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

          element.stop(false, false).animate({
              top: scrollTop < originalY
                      ? 0
                      : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
          }, 300);
      });
  })(jQuery);
});
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/16vqvqev/7/ . I want to accomplish to stop the column following down once it will reach the div with id #stop.

1. How can I make it with this js?
2. I tried to do it with affix bootstrap but didn't go far either... how it would be in that case?

**EDIT:** My website has actually some content before the row with sticky column, so the code is actually like this: https://jsfiddle.net/16vqvqev/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your issue is now fixed with the slight adjustment to your if statement, instead of checking for the height of the window I made it check the final position to where the screen has moved and according to that either stick to top of the #stop or scroll as it did before

https://jsfiddle.net/dmitri_aleksejev/16vqvqev/8/

```
 top: scrollTop 
 - originalY 
 + topMargin 
 + element.height() 
 + parseInt(element.css("padding-bottom"))
 > end 
    ? element.css("top", end - $(element).height() - 60)
    : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
```

instead of:

```
top: scrollTop < originalY
   ? 0
   : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
```

Comment: Great, thank you but I didn't realise to mention that my code has some content before the row, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/16vqvqev/9/ ... it that case, this solution is not working well. Do you think you could edit it a bit? Thanks!

Comment: @Dudis yeah i'll have a look

Comment: is this what you're looking for https://jsfiddle.net/dmitri_aleksejev/16vqvqev/12/

Comment: Almost, if you go back to top, it is going through the CONTENT and it shouldn't... (it should just go together with the column "all the way with you". if you will have time, it will be great if you could look at it once again :) I don't understand it well yet. Thank you, appreciate it!